# SQL Select closest row value to varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I need query which get the closest row but with +/- 10% this tolerance.
For example my var is equal 2.5 and I need select **one** row which is closest 2.5 with tolerance 10% (up and down).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez." Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service - you're expected to at least try to solve it on your own before posting.

Comment: Did you think that I didn't try solve it own? I should write only select * from table? because I don't know what I should do next..

Comment: If you *did*, in fact, try something, please edit the question to show what you tried and what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Personally, it seems to be an interesting question that people new to SQL will not know how to approach (it would be a better question if written more broadly and with more detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda ugly but it should work:

```
select
  *
from
targetTable t
where 
  abs(rowValue-2.5) = (
    select 
      min(abs(rowValue-2.5)) as smallestRowValueDelta
    from
      targetTable
  )
```

Note that this query may match multiple rows in case there are multiple rows with identical smallest delta.

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand what is rowValue

Comment: rowValue is the column that stores the value that you're trying to match with your var